# Integarate Biscom in Salesforce to send FAX

Tags: salesforce, fax

I am new to Salesforce and I have to Integrate Bicom in Salesforce to  send Fax.I have researched alot on this but no luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've answered the same question on developerforce and stackexchange. Unfortunately it doesn't exist, but we created it. Biscom's solution only handled communications between SFDC and a Faxcom server. Everything inside SFDC had to be built. We just finished a full implementation of the Biscom/Faxcom to SFDC, complete with document generation/handling for faxing out from Accounts/Contacts/Cases as well as inbound routing using a barcode to automatically attach the returned fax to the Contact/Case Object. Be happy to discuss further if you're still interested, otherwise you'll want to reach out to Biscom for their basic connector. Here's pics:
[Inbound Fax Wizard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHaST.png) and
[Sending Outbound Fax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flhcT.png)